# How to support text size accessibility in Flutter like Android sp size and iOS Dynamic Type

Tags: flutter, accessibility, font-size

In Android you can set the font size using Scale-independent Pixels (sp) to take into account [user font size preferences](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006972?hl=en) chosen in the settings.

```
android:textSize="26sp"
```

In iOS you can use [Dynamic Type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically) to so something similar.

```
label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

How do you do the same thing in Flutter?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Flutter has [accessibility support for larger fonts](https://flutter.io/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility#large-fonts) built in by default. You can override this behavior by specifying a `textScaleFactor`, which Flutter normally uses to apply the user selected text size.

You can test this by comparing two Text widgets, the second one with `textScaleFactor` set to `1.0`. The default font size for both of them is 14.0 logical pixels.

```
Widget _myWidget() {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Some sample text'),
      Text('Some sample text', textScaleFactor: 1.0),
    ],
  );
}
```

You can get the current text scale factor like this:

```dart
final scale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
```

## Android

In Android settings **Accessibility > Font size** choose the smallest size.

[image]

Do it again and choose the largest size.

[image]

Notice that the first Text widget text changed sizes, but second one with the `textScaleFactor` override didn't.

## iOS

In iOS go to **Settings > General > Accessibility > Larger text** and choose the smallest option.

[image]

And again with the largest setting:

[image]

Comment: But how do I variably control text size while remaining accessible? As you said, `textScaleFactor` overrides the accessibility controls.

Comment: @JoeLapp, You can still set the text size as normal by setting the style property on Text (`style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)`). This allows you to control the text size while remaining accessible.

Comment: Oh! Somehow I came to assume that `fontSize` overrides `textScaleFactor`, but now I see that it doesn't. Thanks! https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/fontSize.html

Comment: Is there a way to get the current text scale? I'd like to rearrange my widgets if the scale is too big

Comment: I think I found it. You can use MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor

Comment: @JoeMuller, Nice! Good to know. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ScreenUtil() package as below:

1- Import library

```
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
```

2- Set inital util

```
@Override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  ScreenUtil.init(context);
  return Scaffold();
}
```

3- Set sp value

```
@Override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  ScreenUtil.init(context);
  return Scaffold(
    Text('Hello World!',
      style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(24))));
}
```

4- (Alternative) Set sp value

```
@Override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  ScreenUtil.init(context);
  return Scaffold(
    Text('Hello World!',
      style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 24.sp)));
}
```